# DD crashing because it ran out of space

Tags: linux, debian, backup, dd

**Question**

I am running `dd` to make a block level backup of my `/home` logical volume, but it keeps running out of space both if I point output to a file on the external drive or pipe the output to `gzip` then to the external drive. Running `df -h` points to the `/` partition(?) running out of space, but I have no idea how to get around this or to just have it dump things on the external drive.

I am making a snapshot of `/home` through `lvcreate` (command I used was `lvcreate -l 477 -s -n HomeSnapshot /dev/Silverback-vg/home`) and then feeding this to `dd` as the input file.

**Context**

I'm trying to setup my homelab with a block level backup of my `/home` and `/` partitions to an image file on my external drive. The goal is to have automated daily full backups that I can just copy back over after reinstalling Debian if I break something (highly likely). I'm coming from a primarily Windows environment, so any questions framed in that context would be helpful. I would also happily accept any documentation you would like to link if you can point out what specifically I should look at, I've spent a couple hours digging and haven't found my solution yet.

**Additional info**

My partitions are as follows:

```
Internal drive (80 GB)
    sda1 = /boot (243 MB)
    sda2 =  Volume Group "Silverback-vg"
        LV root (mounted as /) ~10 GB
        LV swap (mounted as /swap) ~2.64 GB
        LV home (mounted as /home) ~60 GB
External Drive (~3 TB)
    sdb = Volume Group "backups"
        LV 3TB_External (mounted as /mnt/backups/3TB_External) ~3 TB)
```

`df -h` output:

```
root@Silverback:~# df -h
Filesystem                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0                              9.1G  9.1G     0 100% /
udev                                    10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                  403M  6.0M  397M   2% /run
tmpfs                                 1007M   68K 1007M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                              236M   22M  202M  10% /boot
/dev/mapper/Silverback--vg-home         60G   53M   57G   1% /home
tmpfs                                  202M  4.0K  202M   1% /run/user/116
tmpfs                                  202M   12K  202M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mapper/Silverback--vg-HomeBackup   60G   53M   57G   1% /mnt/Silverback-vg/HomeBackup
```

Error from `dd` outputting to external drive:

```
root@Silverback:~# dd if=/dev/Silverback-vg/HomeSnapshot of="/mnt/backups/3TB_External/home Backup Mar-17-2017.img"
dd: writing to ‘/mnt/backups/3TB_External/home Backup Mar-17-2017.img’: No space left on device
8158833+0 records in
8158832+0 records out
4177321984 bytes (4.2 GB) copied, 237.212 s, 17.6 MB/s
```

Error from piping output from `dd` to `gzip` then external drive:

```
root@Silverback:~# dd if=/dev/Silverback-vg/HomeSnapshot | gzip > "/mnt/backups/Home Mar-17-2017.img"

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 1):

For the eagle-eyed among you, I didn't have the `backups` virtual group actually connected to the system, but the `3TB_External` directory was there.  Because it was not mapped as a descendant of `/home`, it was stuck on `/`, which was limited to 10 GB.

When I discovered that, I activated the virtual group with `vgchange -ay backups` then mapped the logical volume to the `3TB_External` directory and was off to the races.

Thank you to everyone who looked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be FAT32 filesystem on the external drive. Change it (format the drive) to NTFS and everything should be fine. FAT32 not allows files bigger than 4GB.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this, but I have a question. The external drive should have been formatted with ext3, where are you seeing it formatted as FAT32?

Also, I caught my own error.  I mistakenly didn't have my external drive mapped to where I was writing data to, so it was dumping the data on the root partition instead.

Comment: I don't see it is FAT32 formatted, but the circumstances are telling me that. But now you have all the info and you can make it work. You should now write to `/mnt/backups/3TB_External`.